# MdxScript(Model)(13,17) Calculation Error: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected

Tags: excel, powerbi, pivot-table, powerquery, powerpivot

I have designed a Hierarchy for the products in a company in a table called Jerarquia, the Hierarchy currently counts with 8 Levels, the measure doesn't give problems until I expand my table to the last level of the Hierarchy where it hands over the message of Calculation Error: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

The code presented below has the intention for the measures of a specific level to not repeat if the level doesn't count with more sub levels.

The variables shown can be described as follows

**Jerarquia[Depth]** is a Function of Power Query that calculates the Depth of a Path

**MaxDepth**

```
=MAX ( Jerarquia[Depth] )
```

**BrowseDepth**

```
=ISFILTERED ( Jerarquia[Level1] )
+ ISFILTERED ( Jerarquia[Level2] )
+ ISFILTERED ( Jerarquia[Level3])
+ISFILTERED(Jerarquia[Level4])
+ISFILTERED ( Jerarquia[Level5] )
+ ISFILTERED ( Jerarquia[Level6] )
+ ISFILTERED ( Jerarquia[Level7])
+ISFILTERED(Jerarquia[Level8])
```

**Ingresos Operacionales** is a numerical variable that is the measure to calculate.

**Jerarquia[IsLeaf]**

```
=
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( Jerarquia ),
    ALL ( Jerarquia ),
    Jerarquia[CatIDNameParent] = EARLIER ( Jerarquia[Category] )
) = 0
```

At last

**Jerarquia[CatIDNameParent]** is the Caterogry ID to which the Product/Category is dependent

**Jerarquia[Category]** is the Category ID/Product

**The Code**

```
Ingresos Operacionales:=IF (
    [BrowseDepth] > [MaxDepth] + 1,
    BLANK (),
    IF (
        [BrowseDepth] = [MaxDepth]+ 1,
        IF (
            AND (
                VALUES (Jerarquia[IsLeaf]) = FALSE,
                SUM ( 'Ventas_por_mes'[Ingresos Operacional] ) <> 0
            ),
            SUM ( 'Ventas_por_mes'[Ingresos Operacional]),
            BLANK ()
        ),
        SUM ('Ventas_por_mes'[Ingresos Operacional])
    )
)
```

[Table With the Herarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R5HS.png)

Answer (score 0):

It does not accept the comparison of `VALUES ( Jerarquia[IsLeaf] ) = FALSE` - it is expecting a single value but `VALUES` returns a single column table.

Did you mean to use `SELECTEDVALUE ( Jerarquia[IsLeaf] )` here?

Comment: I would use SELECTEDVALUE but it is not available for Power Pivot. That is why I had to do a work around.

Comment: Perhaps try a different aggregator then, like `MAX()`

Comment: If you could please be more specific about how I could use MAX() in my code because I cant understand how it would help to fix the problem. Thanks.